# Calling void as a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-animated

I'm reading code from a library and came across this:

```
return Animated.event([null, this.createAnimatedEvent()])(
  event,
  gestureState
)
```

The library uses:

```
    "react": "^16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native": "^0.49.1"
```

I've checked the Animated.event() API and source code for that version and it returns void.

I have a suspicion that it's something to do with PanResponder because of the `gestureState` param but can't connect it together from the docs.

The library is: https://github.com/alexbrillant/react-native-deck-swiper 
and the snippet starts at line 195 in `Swiper.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with it, it seems that Animated.event() is initialized by the array of argument mappings.  Then it returns a function to be called with said arguments.

It's a weird pattern.